# Sublime Text/How to search with multiple criteria

Tags: regex, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bB8Q.jpg)

Hello, 
I would like to utilize a "Find and Replace" function in the sublime Text 3 with multiple criteria but didn't have a good luck to find one yet. I googled it and people said that Using Regex will be a solution on it and I have no idea how to utilize this type of regex thing. Here is what I would like to do on my giant xml documents.

Find:  and 
Where: target folder

Is there any way that I can use "|" in my search box? In advance, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is not terribly clear, i think you need to put code markers around the things you said after "Find:" in your post. because if code is found in questions not surrounded by code markers it will not show.

however, i think i get the juiste, the regex you are looking for is something like this i think:

```
(itemone|itemtwo)
```

where itemone and two are your search terms like so:

[image]

I've never done the case however of replacing based on what regex finds. I think this will just replace either with whatever you specify. Perhaps somone else has tried it.

command is as follows:

- `()` contains
- `|` OR operator

dont be fooled by my picture, that regex matches entire lines.